# CodeIgniter: Using Composer libraries without composer

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php

I have a project where I can't install or use composer.

However, I want to use the OmniPay library, which is a composer package. So I want to just take the libraries out and use them as standard libraries in Code Igniter.

This is what I get from the Composer install (below). If I take them into my `application/libraries/` folder, how can i load them into my controller?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to actually USE Composer on the machine you are developing on, and then commit the vendor folder to the repository.

If you don't want to do this, you'd have to manually do the steps Composer does. And this is more complicated than you think:

The last steps would be to extract the source from the package, put it somewhere suitable, and recreate the autoloading for it. This is the easy step, because the autoloading usually is PSR-0 or PSR-4. "Onmipay/Common" has one addtional class that doesn't fit into this and is loaded as classmap by Composer, so this class has to be handled extra.

The more complicated step before this: Omnipay is also using "guzzle/http" as a HTTP client, and "symfony/http-foundation". These packages also need to be included both as a file and then with their respective autoloading. And these also have dependencies with autoloading and dependencies...

Let Composer do the error-prone work, and commit the vendor folder if you can't provide the infrastructure to add the dependencies later during deployment.